# How to sort accented letters as they are unaccented in php?

Tags: php, sorting, localization, setlocale, asort

I am working on a php code as shown below which on echo returns the array below it.

```
ksort( $alpha_programs );  // Line A
echo '<pre>'; print_r($alpha_programs); echo '</pre>'; // Line B
```

Line B display the following array:

```
Array
(
    [Des Canadiens exceptionnels] 
    [Did You Know?] 
    [Documentaires] 
    [Dossier public] 
    [Débats Vote 2015] 
    [Délibérations de la Chambre des communes] 
    [Délibérations du Sénat] 
)
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above at Line A so that **accented letters should sort as though they are unaccented** as shown below:

```
   Array
    (

       [Débats Vote 2015]
       [Délibérations de la Chambre des communes]
       [Délibérations du Sénat]
       [Des Canadiens exceptionnels]
       [Did You Know?]
       [Documentaires]
       [Dossier public]
    }
```

This is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to sort/work properly.

```
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'fr_CA.utf8');
asort($alpha_programs, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`setlocale`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) function requires the corresponding locale to be available in your system. This varies depending on your platform, but on linux systems you can check available locales by running `locale -a`.

You can check if the function call is failing by checking the return value, since it can return `false`.

If that's the case, you can use a [`Collator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php) from the `intl` extension instead:

```
$collator = Collator::create('fr_CA.utf8');
$collator->sort($alpha_programs);
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/mk96G)

**[Updated Demo](https://3v4l.org/MVRGF) with associative array**

Comment: I haven't posted the complete question. On doing `ksort( $alpha_programs );  // Line A
echo '<pre>'; print_r($alpha_programs); echo '</pre>'; //Line B` it display the following content https://jsfiddle.net/cavhrsfd/

Comment: Sorry, I am using fiddle to show the o/p from php code.

Comment: @flash just [`array_flip`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) your input array.

Comment: like this ?`$result=array_flip($alpha_programs);
$collator = Collator::create('fr_CA.utf8');
$collator->sort($result);`

Comment: @flash You would have to use `asort` now, I updated the demo, but not the answer, since that info wasn't provided in the question.

Comment: Hi, I have one quick [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58192780/how-to-check-if-a-date-falls-between-two-days-of-a-week). It's not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.